# Spring Security - Dynamic Login Section

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

My application is divided to brands. Each employee can login to its own brand/s.
Meaning that one employee with auth to one brand cannot login to other brand.
One user may have few brands.

the login link should look like that: `myapp.com/Management/login/#www.brand.com`
I will parse the www.brand.com in JS and put in a variable when the user login:

```
j_brand:www.brand.com  
j_username:user  
j_password:pass
```

1. how can i verify with the login process that this user belongs to the brand that he requests to login to, and also reject its request if he did not match.
2. when the user logs out, I want to redirect him to the correct page with the brand: `myapp.com/Management/login/#www.brand.com`, how can i add the `#www.brand.com` to the redirect path.

I am implementing `UserDetailsService` in my login process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's a possible answer for part 1.  I don't know about your second question off the top of my head, though I have an idea that you can pursue.  I have done something similar in modifying the login process, though.

For part 1, there are two steps:

First: Write a custom security filter that adds the additional brand check validation.

```
public class BrandAwareUserPasswordAuthenticationkFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {   

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        Authencation auth = super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);

        if(!userBelongsToBrand()) {    // you're on your own here
            throw new BadCredentialsException("your message here"); // you can elect to throw a different exception
        }

        return auth;
    }
}
```

Second: Instantiate your filter and wire it in to spring security in place of the default user/password authentication filter.  You may want to play with some of the config settings I have here...I'm copying them from my project's file.

```
<bean name="brandAwareFilterBean" class="com.drumpus.webapp.LoginVelocityCheckFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/doLogin"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/account/"/>
            <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?failed=true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>


<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">

    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="brandAwareFilterBean"/>

    <!-- the rest of your config -->

</security:http>
```

For question number 2, I believe your key will be looking into creating a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and plugging it in to your new filter.  Having never done that, though, I can't give you very specific advice.

Good luck, and hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but my auth process is using `UserDetailsService`. can i combine them together?

Comment: Yes.  The `UserDetailsService` will already be injected into the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` superclass, so you'll have it on-hand in your filter.  The superclass will use it for authentication per normal, and it's just up to you to add the custom functionality.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for this Steve. This was the last piece I was missing to customize my role/permission handling.  The only thing missing is where the target bean for the entry point reference "authenticationEntryPoint" comes from.

Comment: No problem.  It's been a while since I looked at this, but I believe that bean is created as a side-effect of pulling in the `<security:http/>` element.  It creates a whole mess of beans and adds them to the application context.